# Error Inserting data from an AJAX POST using a prepared statement

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I’m currently creating a Facebook Canvas game and at the moment I have a php script which inserts player data (received from an AJAX post) into my database. This data is taken from Facebook’s Graph API in a Javascript function and then sent by AJAX to the php script. Everything’s working perfectly right now, but it’s not secure against SQL injection.

I want to make my SQL queries more secure so I have been reading up on Prepared Statements, Bound Parameters/Parameterized Statements and Sanitizing Data, but I’m finding it all a little confusing.

I understand how SQL injection works, and the idea behind using a prepared statement, but I’m having difficulty implementing it when trying to insert data that’s been received by AJAX. This is my most recent attempt:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php';

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('myappid', 'myappsecret');

$servername = "myservername";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO player (fb_id, f_name, l_name, email, gender) VALUES 
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $userid, $userfirst_name, $userlast_name, $useremail, $usergender);

// set parameters (these variables are received from AJAX) and execute
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$userfirst_name = $_POST['userfirst_name'];
$userlast_name = $_POST['userlast_name'];
$useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
$usergender = $_POST['usergender'];
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Sadly nothing is inserting into my database when I try this. The Facebook data is definitely reaching the php script (because it inserted successfully before I tried implementing this prepared statement) so maybe the problem is in the “prepare and bind” section?

I’d be grateful if anyone would have any idea of what could be wrong here, or any other advice on making this more secure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't you think `$smt = ...` and `$stmt->bind ...` should come after `$usergender=$_POST['usergender'];`

Comment: Hi @VarunNaharia thanks for your reply, I've tried that but it's still not working. Is it possible that some of the code is depreciated?